# Firebase Auth works with normal Google accounts, but not school/education Google accounts

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication

I'm creating a standard webapp that uses Firebase Authentication to allow the user to sign in with a Google popup. Everything works fine for normal google accounts (gmail, yahoo, whatever.). However, the main audience for this app will be using school accounts. These school accounts are using Google Workspace I believe, and are managed by the school. (Ex: john.doe@fpcs.org). *The probem here is that when I use a school account, Authentication with Google breaks with these 2 error messages.*

```
POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=bIzaSyDwvveryrealkey3mZdrlUaEunUemYakZ9gddx1ZnGgnQ 400
```

```
Firebase: Failed to fetch resource from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo, http status: 401, http response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
 (auth/invalid-credential).
```

Again, this error does not show up when using normal email accounts. I haven't been able to find much documentation on Google Workspace accounts. I've also noticed that my problem is not unique - when I use my school account to try and log in via Google on other websites (quizlet.com, I'm sure there's more), it also breaks - coming up with a generic error page. I've never noticed this error on quizlet because, before I can log in usually, Chrome browser specifically comes up with a dialog saying "Signing you in..." whenever I visit. However, if you bypass this dialog and try and log in with the "Sign in with Google" button on the page, you get (presumably) the same error.

**Is there a way to fix this? Is there some setting that the adminstrators Google Workspace have turned on that doesn't allow 3rd party authentication?**

I've looked at the documentation for Firebase and Google Authentication and didn't find much, some of the docs for Google were outdated and confusing. I realize this problem is hard to replicate because you need a managed Google Workspace account. I'm just looking for a general direction - what are the capabilities of google workspace?